# Disabling checkbox after it has been checked

Tags: javascript

I am using JSF and Javascript

**Checkbox**

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="handlePaymentButtons()" 
class="chkBox"></h:selectBooleanCheckbox>Yes I agree terms and Conditions
```

**JS**

```
<script>
            function handlePaymentButtons(){
                console.log("we are here..");

                var box = document.getElementsByClassName("chkBox");
                box.disabled =true;
                console.log(box);
                gButton.enable();

            }
        </script>
```

I simply want to disable the currently checked checkbox.

[image]

but i can still check/uncheck the checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a `HTMLCollection`, a collection, returned value of `getElementsByClassName`. You either need to iterate through it or get a specific element by index from the collection. Since the `.length` of the collection is `1`, you can simply code `box[0].disabled = true`.

Alternatively, you can also use `querySelector` which returns only one element (if any):

```
var box = document.querySelector(".chkBox");
box.disabled = true;
```

Comment: alternate solution looks great and exactly what i needed.